# How to Compress JSON with ASP?

Tags: jquery, json, iis, asp-classic, gzip

I have a large JSON data string that's 757KB.  I tried GZIP'ing it, which successfully reduced file size down to 143KB.  But, in it's GZIP'ed state, my JQUERY function can't make use of the compressed JSON data.

Any suggestions on how to compress JSON in an IIS/ASP environment and still be able to use the JSON data in a JQUERY function?

Comment: This should be something that IIS should be able to handle for you, I'd think.  I'm not an IIS expert; in fact I'm not familiar with it at all.

Comment: Do you have dynamic compression activated?

Comment: I tried dynamic compression, and didn't detect the slightest bit of improvement

Comment: you were missing the `application/json` type, look at my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Hope this helps:

- [Activate Dynamic Compression](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753681%28WS.10%29.aspx)
- Open SystemDir (C:\Windows\System32) and find this file: `inetsvr\config\applicationhost.config`
- Find the `<dynamicTypes>` tag.
  Be sure you have 
      `<add mimeType="application/json" enabled="true" />` in the list.
- Try reducing the amount of data you pass. 757KB is a LOT of information.
  If you pass HTML, you are doing it wrong. Pass the data and render it client side.
  If you are passing plain data, you are probably passing too much of it; try splitting it in more requests, in order to let the user show part of the whole information while still loading it.

Comment: I'm running IIS6.0 that folder/file do not exist in my installation.  Do you know where to flip that switch in IIS6.0?

The data is as spartan as I can make it. It consists of: id, text, image

Here's an example:
{"id":"10071750","text":"Video Capture System for TICs, w&#47; Flash Memory Card, Card Reader, Li-ion Battery, and Storage Case by Cairns |10071750| $5199.99","image":"image_name.gif"}

There's 5000+ iterations of these

Comment: I found this  http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/5bce429d-c4a7-4f9e-a619-5972497b932a.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: I added: htm, html, css, js, txt, log to static compression
I added: asp, dll, exe to dynamic compression

I then restarted the webserver, thinking IIS may need to be restarted for the changes to take effect.

According to Firebug there is 0 reduction in filesize.