# Minify Large PostBack data to the server?

Tags: asp.net, performance

Is there anyway which I can `shrink` ( like `gzip`) a `post data` , before i send it to the server ?

My page contains 1 big `textbox` `multi line`. and the user paste very large text inside it.

so the post data - its bigg. ( and it works) but it works `slowly`.

is there anyway i can `speed up` thing there ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try to compress the data client side with JavaScript before sending, and to use Ajax post.

for example there are JQuery plugins for this which simplify very much the task:

[JSEND - AJAX POST REQUEST COMPRESSION & ENCODING](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jSEND)

Comment: I'll guess i'll put the zippped data in hiddenField and then post it. I dont want to activate Ajax now.. Thanks

Comment: Ajax is not a bad think is actually essential and easy if you are in .NET 3.5 or higher. Check this one as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2515421/how-to-compress-json-with-asp

Comment: Im pretty good in ajax but its just a memo text box for me to access from every computer im in...